# How to check the physical existence of new members in a database?

Tags: database, user-accounts

I'm really sorry if StackOverflow is not a place to discuss this matter. Also, I am not a programmer.

This is what I'm trying to learn about: how to legally check that a registration of a new member on an app or a website, corresponds to a real physical person, with a pretty high level of accuracy / security. As an example, many gambling websites have this kind of technology. Is there a public database (maybe provided by governments?) that can be used to match new members with verified physical people? I know even Facebook is having a hard time doing that.

I am looking for suggestions, and out of the box thinking, on the most reliable way to insure that one account = one physical person only. Also any links on this subject will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can legally do that.

Comment: I think some gambling websites have fairly secure systems, such as poker websites, to identify that a person is a real person, in particular for payments and preventing cheating...

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks everyone 